# Visualize Maven dependencies excluding test scope

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I would like to generate a diagram including all of a maven module's dependencies, for all scopes **except** test.  I've been using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1, which has a nice UI when selecting 'Show Dependencies' from a pom file.  However, you can only select 1 scope, or all scopes.  All scopes is very cluttered due to test-scoped dependencies like arquillian.  I'd like to show compile+provided+runtime.

I'm assuming that IntellJ is using the maven dependency:tree plugin underneath, whose scope options are the same.  Are there any other convenient ways to do this either within IntelliJ or through a maven plugin?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the dependency plugin. From [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#scope): *The scope to filter by when resolving the dependency tree, or null to include dependencies from all scopes. Note that this feature does not currently work due to MNG-3236.* And this issue was renamed to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-4

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea) has a nice visualization of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks.  I should clarify that I'm looking for diagrams the way that IntelliJ's dependency viewer provides.  I don't see that at least in the screenshots for the tool.

Comment: Right, it only has a tree, but I find diagram useless for bigger projects anyway... . You need to make a feature request for your case on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com .

Comment: Upvoting for reminding me that we pay for support :)